# Can't get textures to XRReferenceImageLibrary from assetBundle

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets, assetbundle

AssetBundle has paths to images in the asset bundle file but I can't extract it to use in runtime
[References in asset bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mboh0.png)

```
private static void Initialize(AssetBundle myLoadedAssetBundle)
    {
        if (myLoadedAssetBundle == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var manager = FindObjectOfType<ARTrackedImageManager>();

        var dependencies = myLoadedAssetBundle.LoadAllAssets();

        foreach (var dependence in dependencies)
        {
            if (dependence is XRReferenceImageLibrary library)
            {
                manager.referenceLibrary = library;
            }
        }


        myLoadedAssetBundle.Unload(false);
    }
```

So I get empty textures in the reference image library in unity:
[So I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAluf.png)